# Calling calculation function in adapter class to java class?

Tags: java, android, android-adapter, calculation

I have Cart activity where user can add,update and delete their cart. Each of the function has it owns java activity and I also have CartAdapter activity. I want to perform a calculation that can display the total price of customer item in the ViewCart activity. I did the calculation on CartAdapter but I have a problem with displaying the totalPrice inside my ViewCart activity.

I got error that said

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "99.00"
>           at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
>           at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:801)
>           at com.example.g.Customer.CartAdapter.onBindViewHolder(CartAdapter.java:68)
>           at com.example.g.Customer.CartAdapter.onBindViewHolder(CartAdapter.java:28)

Here is my `CartAdapter`

```
   public class CartAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CartAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private Context context;


    List<String> key;


    ArrayList<Cart> CartList;

    int totalPrice = 0;
    int totalPrice1 = 0;


    public CartAdapter(ArrayList<Cart> CartListList) {
        this.CartList = CartListList;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cust_view_cart, viewGroup, false);

        context = viewGroup.getContext();
        return new CartAdapter.MyViewHolder(view);
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder myViewHolder, final int i) {

        Picasso.with(context).load(CartList.get(i).getPro_image()).into(myViewHolder.image);
        myViewHolder.name.setText(CartList.get(i).getPro_name());
        myViewHolder.category.setText(CartList.get(i).getPro_category());
        myViewHolder.price.setText(CartList.get(i).getPro_price());
        myViewHolder.size.setText(CartList.get(i).getSize());
        myViewHolder.quantity.setText(CartList.get(i).getQuantity());


        totalPrice1 = (int)Double.parseDouble((CartList.get(i).getPro_price())) * Integer.valueOf(CartList.get(i).getQuantity());
        totalPrice = totalPrice + totalPrice1;




        myViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String cart_id = CartList.get(i).getCart_id();
                String keyB = CartList.get(i).getBrand_id();
                String pid = CartList.get(i).getPro_id();
                String cust_id = CartList.get(i).getCust_id();
                String name = CartList.get(i).getPro_name();
                String category = CartList.get(i).getPro_category();
                String price = CartList.get(i).getPro_price();
                String image = CartList.get(i).getPro_image();
                String size = CartList.get(i).getSize();
                String quantity = CartList.get(i).getQuantity();


                Intent intent = new Intent(context, UpdateCart.class);
                intent.putExtra("cust_id", cust_id);
                intent.putExtra("Cart_id", cart_id);
                intent.putExtra("keyB", keyB);
                intent.putExtra("pid", pid);
                intent.putExtra("pro_name", name);
                intent.putExtra("pro_category", category);
                intent.putExtra("pro_price", price);
                intent.putExtra("pro_image", image);
                intent.putExtra("size", size);
                intent.putExtra("quantity", quantity);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        myViewHolder.btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String pro_name = CartList.get(i).getPro_name();
                String cart_id = CartList.get(i).getCart_id();
                String cust_id = CartList.get(i).getCust_id();
                DatabaseReference dbCart = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Cart").child(cust_id);
                dbCart.child(cart_id).removeValue();

                //set url of image to storageref
                StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(CartList.get(i).getPro_image());
                // Delete the file
                storageReference.delete().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        // File deleted successfully
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Exception exception) {
                        // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
                    }
                });

                //Toolbar
                // Remove the item on remove/button click
                CartList.remove(i);
                /*
                    Parameters
                        position : Position of the item that has now been removed
                */
                notifyItemRemoved(i);

                /*
                    Parameters
                        positionStart : Position of the first item that has changed
                        itemCount : Number of items that have changed
                */
                notifyItemRangeChanged(i, CartList.size());

                // Show the removed item label
                Toast.makeText(context, pro_name + " has been removed from your cart", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return CartList.size();
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView name, category, price, size, quantity;
        ImageView image, btnDelete;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            category = itemView.findViewById(R.id.category);
            image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            price = itemView.findViewById(R.id.price);
            size = itemView.findViewById(R.id.size);
            quantity = itemView.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
            btnDelete = itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete);


        }
    }
}
```

`ViewCart`

```
   public class ViewCart extends AppCompatActivity {

    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    FirebaseUser currentUser;
    ArrayList<Cart> CartList;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    private int totalPrice = 0;
    TextView total;


    private String userID, cust_id;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_cart);

        total = findViewById(R.id.total);

        total.setText( String.valueOf(totalPrice));

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

        if (currentUser != null) {
            userID = currentUser.getUid();
            cust_id = firebaseAuth.getUid();
            databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Cart").child(cust_id);
            recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv);
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

            databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    CartList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                        CartList.add(ds.getValue(Cart.class));
                    }

                    CartAdapter cartAdapter = new CartAdapter(CartList);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(cartAdapter);

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        } else
            openDialog();

    }

    private void openDialog() {

        LoginDialog loginlDialog = new LoginDialog();
        loginlDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "login dialog");

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
   public class ViewCart extends AppCompatActivity {

    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    FirebaseUser currentUser;
    ArrayList<Cart> CartList;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    private int totalPrice = 0;
    TextView total;


    private String userID, cust_id;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_cart);

        total = findViewById(R.id.total);
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

        if (currentUser != null) {
            userID = currentUser.getUid();
            cust_id = firebaseAuth.getUid();
            databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Cart").child(cust_id);
            recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv);
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

            databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    CartList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                        CartList.add(ds.getValue(Cart.class));
                        Cart cart = ds.getValue(Cart.class);
                        totalPrice = totalPrice + (int)Double.parseDouble(cart.getPrice()) *  Integer.valueOf(cart.getQuantity());

                    }

                    CartAdapter cartAdapter = new CartAdapter(CartList);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(cartAdapter);
                    total.setText( String.valueOf(totalPrice));

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        } else
            openDialog();

    }

    private void openDialog() {

        LoginDialog loginlDialog = new LoginDialog();
        loginlDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "login dialog");

    }
```

Comment: thank you it works but it didn't fetch the amount in the my main activity. I call it like this  total.setText(String.valueOf(totalPrice)); in my ViewCart activity did i call it correctly? btw i declare the int totalPrice=0; and it display the 0 value in my ViewCart. It did not fetch the value that it supposed to be.

Comment: can you post your activity code where you use total price variable

Comment: I've posted the full code of my ViewCart activity and CartAdapter.

Comment: why  do you want to fetch the total price in activity

Comment: and whats the purpose of using totalPrice

Comment: because i want to display it on my ViewCart activity.  So that user that have added their item in cart can see the total price that need to pay before proceed to the next activity. The function of totalPrice is to put the calculation method that I'have done in the adapter class to the ViewCart activity. If I don't use the variable of totalPrice then how can I display the total amount that user have to pay? Please correct me if I'm wrong, I'm totally new in android and want to learn.

Comment: I have red line on the (i) in (CartList.get(i).getPro_price())) and (CartList.get(i).getQuantity()) is it because the i is not declare?

Comment: `totalPrice = totalPrice + (int)Double.parseDouble((CartList.get(i).getPro_price())) *  Integer.valueOf(CartList.get(i).getQuantity());`

I think it didn't recognize the **'i'** because it says Cannot resolve symbol 'i'

Comment: It works thank you but I have encountered another problem when i clicked on the delete cart button where user can delete the item that they don't want to buy. The Amount didn't get deducted but instead it keep increasing why it happen? I've accepted your answer and voted it. If you don't my to answer my other questions about the delete cart where the amount didn't get deducted but instead it keep increasing.

Comment: do you use github

Comment: I will ask another question If you don't mind tag you too to my question. I don't use github but I have the account.

Comment: ok i will try or do one thing push your project to git i will solve the problem

Comment: sir, how can I tag you to my new problem questions?

Comment: Do one thing, first ask a question then post the link of the question in comment

Comment: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58760938/how-to-fetch-user-id-to-perform-a-display-list-in-android-studio-for-admin-to-vi)

Comment: I've tried to tag you to my questions. But it didn't worked. I have included the link of my questions.

Answer (score 0):

**Why have you kept `price` as `String` , instead of `float` or `int`?**

You probably have kept `price` as `String` so that you can display it in `TextView`, but with this you are forced to cast it every time.

You should keep price as float and to set it as text in `TextView` simply use `string concatenation`  :

```
float price = 99.00;
textView.setText(value+ "");
```