# How to fetch user id to perform a display list in android studio for admin to view the order list?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to display a customer order list inside my admin page. But it gives me blank page with no error inside the logcat.

Below is my database:

[image: The highlighted id is the customer id and the blue line is the pro_id which is the order id of the customer. I want to view this list on my admin Order Received page]

I want to display the Order inside the Order List. The highlighted id is the id of the customer. I called the database like this:

```
databaseReference FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Order");
```

I don't get the error but I did not get the exact output that I need. Here is the problem that I faced when running my apps.

As we can see is true that inside order database it has 3 ids. but the apps did not fetch the id. How can I call the user id to display it inside my order list page?
[image]

I'm expecting the the result that it will display the id of the customer that have make the order. From the picture above I'm expecting that the Customer Id will display the id of `YQg0kFIUkXW0Z909XcI0XDIdeGt2`, `06E02IpRO3RzWp2RQHfr7XVYsuo2` and `wmzfhWTdA0U9Jh8ENnGJG6IPiNE2`instead of abc. The reason why it display the abc is because I set the textview as abc for hint.

The same id got duplicated.

[image]

```
     databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Order");
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                orderList = new ArrayList<>();

                for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            for (DataSnapshot orderSnapshot : userSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                orderList.add(orderSnapshot.getValue(Order.class));
            }
        }

                psOrderAdapter PsOrderAdapter = new psOrderAdapter(orderList);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(PsOrderAdapter);
//                Log.d("TAG", "Number of orders: " + orderList.size());


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(ManageOrder.this, databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    }
```

`Order class`

```
public class Order {
    public String cust_id;
    public String pro_id;
    public String total;
    public String name;
    public String address;
    public String phone;
    public String status;


    public Order() {
    }

    public Order(String cust_id, String pro_id, String total, String name, String address, String phone, String status) {
        this.cust_id = cust_id;
        this.total = total;
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.pro_id = pro_id;
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getCust_id() {
        return cust_id;
    }

    public void setCust_id(String cust_id) {
        this.cust_id = cust_id;
    }

    public String getPro_id() {
        return pro_id;
    }

    public void setPro_id(String pro_id) {
        this.pro_id = pro_id;
    }

    public String getTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    public void setTotal(String total) {
        this.total = total;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

Comment: @kam1234 can you help me for this one?

Comment: What do you mean through "but the apps did not fetch the id"? Please add a screenshot of your database that contains the data under those random children and tell us the expected result.

Comment: I have updated the information of my problems @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data structure seems to be:

```
Orders: {
  uid1: {
    orderid1: { ... },
    orderid3: { ... }
  },
  uid2: {
    orderid2: { ... },
    orderid4: { ... }
  }
}
```

So you have two dynamic levels under `Orders`: one for the UID, and one for the order IDs. Since you're listening for the data under all of `Orders`, your `onDataChange` will need to contain a separate loop for each of these dynamic levels.

Right now you have one loop, which means that your `ds` refers to the data for a user, while you're then trying to read a order from it. Please use better variable names in the future, as it can help you find problems like this much more easily.

The correct approach is to first loop over the users, and then inside that loop over the orders for that user.

Something like:

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Order");
databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        orderList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            for (DataSnapshot orderSnapshot : userSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                orderList.add(orderSnapshot.getValue(Order.class));
            }
        }

        psOrderAdapter PsOrderAdapter = new psOrderAdapter(orderList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(PsOrderAdapter);
    }
```

Comment: thank you it worked. But I noticed that if the customer have more than 1 product id under the same customer id. The list get duplicate. What i mean here is the same customer id get duplicated.

Comment: Just a quick references for you. I've added the picture of the id that got duplicated

Comment: From the code that is the expected behavior. You're showing a list of orders, so if a single customer has multiple orders, the details for that customer will be showed for each order. You could show customers, and then under them their orders, but that'd be a different view (and I honestly don't know the view type handles this on Android).